# How do you get a double-column unique key as foreign key?

Tags: sql, mariadb, foreign-keys, constraints, unique-key

I have the following two tables in MariaDB 11.0.2:

```
CREATE TABLE `Languages` (
  `Name` char(49) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISO_639_1` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `Language_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Main_Flag` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Language_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Languages_UN` (`ISO_369_1`,`Main_Flag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=136 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `Tests` (
  `Test_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Test_Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISO_639_1` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `Main_Flag` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Test_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=136 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

but I cannot assign the double column unique-key to their counterparts:

```
MariaDB [my_db]> ALTER TABLE  Tests ADD CONSTRAINT Test_Language_FK FOREIGN KEY (ISO_639_1, Main_Flag) REFERENCES Languages(ISO_639_1, Main_Flag);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `my_db`.`Tests` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

There are no anomalies in the index of the Test table:

```
MariaDB [my_db]> show index from Tests;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Tests |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | Test_ID     | A         |          37 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
1 row in set (0,001 sec)
```

What is holding me back? The data types are the same and the collation and charsets are also a match.

Comment: The columns in the unique key don’t match the ones you are using in the reference

Comment: Right, that's where the bad index came from. Thanks =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a bit cryptic, you can get some more info by using

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

In the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section you'll see `constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns`

You require and index

```
CREATE INDEX MYINDEX ON Languages (ISO_639_1, Main_Flag);
```

See this [working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SBpq6b22)

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir! I don't see a reason why we should index columns if we want a two-column foreign key, but that is how things are ‍♂️

Thanks =))

Answer (score 0):

The best with inno den is to run the last comand, so that you try much the information about the error.

In your you are missing a unique or primary key in the referenced table for the column combination

```
CREATE TABLE `Languages` (
  `Name` char(49) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISO_639_1` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `Language_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Main_Flag` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Language_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_language` (`ISO_639_1`,`Main_Flag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=136 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `Tests` (
  `Test_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Test_Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISO_639_1` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `Main_Flag` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Test_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=136 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
ALTER TABLE  Tests 
ADD CONSTRAINT
  Test_Language_FK FOREIGN KEY (ISO_639_1, Main_Flag)
  REFERENCES Languages(ISO_639_1, Main_Flag);
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
show engine innodb status
```

| Type | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| InnoDB |  | ===================================== 2023-07-29 20:36:04 0x7f8018926700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M_3P1-QW)